# Batch file to delete all *.auc files in %LOCALAPPDATA% for a specified user?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to build a batch file to delete all *.auc  files in %LOCALAPPDATA% for a specified user. Like maybe to have it ask for a username and then use that as the target for the delete function?

I tried to look around but couldn't figure out a way to do it with both the wildcard and a specified user. In all fairness I am pretty new at this. We have users who pretty regularly have to delete these files, while we are troubleshooting the underlying cause, it would be nice to simplify this process as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below (not TESTED though but should work fine)

```
@echo off    
set /p uname="Enter user ID: "    
set path_firstpart = "C:\Users\"    
set path_secondpart = "\AppData\Local"    
set pathtodeletein = %path_firstpart%%uname%%path_secondpart%        
del "%pathtodeletein%\*.auc" /S /Q
```

If you want to provide this batch for the current user you can use %LOCALAPPDATA% as the path to delete in or use %username% in order to avoid asking for the username.
If you want more fancy user interaction you could switch to windows scripting host and vbscript (phew ...) which allows you to open input boxes.

Comment: I believe there is a certain risk if you run this on e.g. D:\. It will change the directory of drive C but not change the drive. So effectively you would delete all *.auc files in D:. You should in my opinion skip the "cd" line, not use %PATH% and delete differently: del "%pathtodelete%\*.auc" /S /Q

Comment: @Marged, shouldn't be since the default root directory generally is `C:` but may be the case and so may need little modification on top of the answer given. That's why mentioned as [NOT TESTED]

Comment: open a dosbox, change to drive D: and then issue "cd C:\somepath". You will stay on D:. And I just meant to improve your code, so this is no big deal ;-) The OP still has to test both evolutions of the batch file

Comment: This ALMOST works. It actually deleted all .auc files on the system. (which is something that is handy to have as well) Any ideas on how to get it to specify correctly?

Comment: It appears to be ignoring the variables all together and just deleting all files matching *.auc on the c drive.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help fellas! It was a formatting issue, had to remove a bunch of spaces. 
`@echo off
set /p uname=Enter user ID:
set path_firstpart=C:\Users\
set path_secondpart=\AppData\Local
set pathtodeletein=%path_firstpart%%uname%%path_secondpart%
del %pathtodeletein%*.auc /S /Q
pause`